# Table create from PHP fails

Tags: php, sql, validation

```
    <?php  

    $db_host = "localhost"; 
    $db_username = "root"; 
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "onlinestores"; 

      // Run the actual connection here  
    $connect_dude=mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");


    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
     }
    ?>

    //creating table
    <?php
    include "connect_to_db.php";
    $sql_command="CREATE TABLE admin(
        id NOT NULL auto_increment,
        username varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        password varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        last_login date NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        UNIQUE KEY username(username)
        )";
    if(mysqli_query($connect_dude,"$sql_command")){
    echo "ookie dookie";
    }else {
    echo "it didn't work";
    }
    ?>
```

The code doesn't create any table in the database and shows me echo statement "it didn't work".

Comment: *sidenote:* why do you need double quotes in `mysqli_connect()` & `mysqli_query()` ?

Comment: does the database exist?

Comment: Does the account you used to login have `CREATE` permission ?

Comment: Error message only help to decide which type of error this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL has syntax errors.

- `id` column misses `int`
- `UNIQUE KEY username(username)` should be `UNIQUE KEY(username)`

Try this:

```
$sql_command = "CREATE TABLE admin 
(id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
username varchar(16) NOT NULL,
password varchar(16) NOT NULL,
last_login date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE KEY(username))";
```

To catch errors in mysql calls, use [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

```
else {
    echo "it didn't work because: " . mysqli_error($connect_dude);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,boss.I appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, make sure you have proper names for variables before pushing code on production,

connect_to_db.php file:

```
<?php
  $db_host = "localhost"; 
  $db_username = "root"; 
  $db_pass = "";
  $db_name = "onlinestores"; 

  // Run the actual connection here  
  $mysqli=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);

  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
  }
?>
```

create_table.php file:

```
<?php
  include "connect_to_db.php";

  $sql_command="CREATE TABLE admin(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
    pass VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    last_login DATE NOT NULL
  )";

  if($mysqli->query($sql_command) === TRUE)
    echo "ookie dookie";
  else
    echo "it didn't work";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**replace your code:**

```
$db_host = "localhost"; 
    $db_username = "root"; 
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "onlinestores"; 

      // Run the actual connection here  
    $connect_dude=mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");


    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
     }
    ?>

    //creating table
    <?php
    include "connect_to_db.php";
    $sql_command="CREATE TABLE admin(
        id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
        username varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        password varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        last_login date NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        UNIQUE KEY username(username)
        )";
    if(mysqli_query($connect_dude,"$sql_command")){
    echo "ookie dookie";
    }else {
    echo "it didn't work";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This does not affect the result. Variables in double quotes will be parsed & substituted.