# Mysql create table and insert at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

```
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$id` (
                    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `start` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                  `end` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=45 ;


                INSERT INTO `$id`(`start`, `end`) VALUES ('0','0')
```

I have been trying to figure out how I can bind these two Mysql(requests(?)) into one with no success. Basically I want it to work so when I create the table it should also add the values 0 and 0 to "start" and "end" rows. But I still want the "Create table if not exists" to be in effect for the INSERT INTO. So if the table exist don't INSERT either.

Comment: `VALUES ('0','0')` since they're VARCHAR - Plus, where is `$id` coming from?

Comment: $id is from another part of the program, which will look something like this " 76561197961581096"

Comment: OK. Well you'd still need to use `VALUES ('0','0')` since `start` and `end` are VARCHAR.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected that

Comment: Any idéa how to get the insert into the create table?

Comment: Since your `date` is `NOT NULL`, have you tried adding a value to your query?

Comment: @Fred-ii- There's a default value for this column. That should work fine.

Comment: @VMai My mistake; I stand corrected.

Comment: Only thing I can see is adding a semi-colon at the end `INSERT INTO...  VALUES ('0','0');` see if that makes it kick in.

Comment: Oh, i must have explained it wrong, I want so the "INSERT INTO" is a part of the "CREATE TABLE" so one single mysql request, possible?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve that is not clear. this exact query works for me it creates the table if not exists and inserts data.

Comment: I doubt that's possible to do. If you want to do that, you will need to do it outside of PHPmyadmin or other program you're using, with PHP etc.

Comment: Here is an example link http://codewalkers.com/c/a/Database-Code/MySQL-InstaTable/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/21397704/

Answer (score -1):

You could do that with following single statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$id` (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `start` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `end` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
SELECT '0' AS `start`, '0' AS `end`;
```

You use the `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` syntax with selecting not from a table, but constant values and get the autoincrement value and the current_timestamp by default.

as of MySQL 5.5.6 or newer, see following excerpt from the [manual, CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html):

> As of MySQL 5.5.6, handling of CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... SELECT
>   statements was changed for the case that the destination table already
>   exists. This change also involves a change in MySQL 5.1 beginning with
>   5.1.51.
>
> Previously, for CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... SELECT, MySQL produced
>   a warning that the table exists, but inserted the rows and wrote the
>   statement to the binary log anyway. By contrast, CREATE TABLE ...
>   SELECT (without IF NOT EXISTS) failed with an error, but MySQL
>   inserted no rows and did not write the statement to the binary log.
>
> MySQL now handles both statements the same way when the destination
>   table exists, in that neither statement inserts rows or is written to
>   the binary log. The difference between them is that MySQL produces a
>   warning when IF NOT EXISTS is present and an error when it is not.
>
> This change means that, for the preceding example, the CREATE TABLE IF
>   NOT EXISTS ... SELECT statement inserts nothing into the destination
>   table as of MySQL 5.5.6.